# Copying a file using VBS in to a Windows Directory, getting permission denied

Tags: vbscript, attributes, permission-denied, file-copying

I'm trying to simplify an install for a group of people I work with that have very little computer skills.  I have a vbs script that copies various configuration files in to their proper directories.  However, there is one file that I cannot get to copy.

I am trying to copy a new file called hosts in to the C:\windows\systems32\drivers\etc folder and I keep getting permission denied no matter what I do.

```
Const OverWriteExisting = True
Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile "C:\users\IBM_ADMIN\Desktop\Colgate Socks\hosts", "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", OverWriteExisting
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you're running it from a shell (i.e. command prompt)?  If so, are you using "Run as administrator" to launch the shell?

Comment: If all the computers are on domain, you need to run it with an account which is member of 'Domain Administrators'.

Answer (score 2):

Run as administrator?

You can do this through task scheduler easily.

Another option was from [How to run scripts as administrator in Windows 7?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/Fb-YibxZ2x8)

Put this at the start of your script

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
 " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
Else
[your code here]
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this %windir%\Sysnative instead of C:\Windows\System32.